# Как сохранить фотографию после того как сфотографировал

Tags: android, файловая-система, камера

В своём приложении через startActivityForResult открываю камеру,фотографирую.
В onActivityResult img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail) фотография показывается, но когда пытаюсь сохранить фото в файловую систему,создаётся файл .jpg но вместо фото там чёрный фон. Что я делаю не так и как правильно?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1112;
public static final String TAG = "TAG";

File myDir = null;


@BindView(R.id.camera_btn)
Button cameraBtn;
@BindView(R.id.img)
ImageView img;
@BindView(R.id.info)
TextView info;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    myDir = new File("/sdcard/myPics/");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Log.d(TAG, myDir.getAbsolutePath());
}

@OnClick(R.id.camera_btn)
public void onViewClicked() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
    File f = null;
    try {
        f = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));


}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";


    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,
            ".jpg",
            myDir.getAbsoluteFile());

    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

}

Comment: На какой версии андроида проверяете? Работает ли на версиях < 7? С седьмой версии изменились правила работы с файловой системой. Возможно проблема в этом.

Comment: проверяю андроид 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что у вас выскакивает `FileUriExposedException`, начиная с API Level=24 запрещено во внешний `Intent` напрямую передавать `file://`

Надо или исхитриться и схему `file://` переделать в `content://` (надо писать собственный `ContentProvider` маскирующий `file://` или воспользоваться коробочным провайдером `FileProvider`

Подробнее, [например здесь](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)